# Is this symbol for the letter N common?

Tags: alphabet

Consider the picture below, depicting a cross allegedly found by monks of Galstonbury Abbey in a tomb (allegedly) containing the remains of King Arthur.

[image]

It's suppose to say:

> Hic jacet sepultus inclitus rex Arturius in insula Avalonia

(source of quote and image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon))

I find odd that the N is depicted like an H. Notice there is also another H (*Hic*), but they might not be the same (the latter has a thinner middle stroke). Is this representation of N common to a region/period? Or is it rare? I've never seen it before. There is no mention of it in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet), for instance. Searching [this index](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Inscriptions/Index/home.html) of Latin inscriptions seems to show no such use for H either. N seems to be always used for N.

Comment: In Cyrillic Н is also sometimes with a horizontal bar and sometimes with an [angled bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Cyrillic_alphabet). Probably just a small change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was somewhat common in the Middle Ages for capital N to have an horizontal connective stroke, resembling H, at least in manuscript. Here are a few examples of abbreviations using capital N, taken from [Cappelli](http://www.ub.uni-koeln.de/cdm/ref/collection/mono20/id/8533) (Roman numerals are centuries):

[image]

[image]

[image]